# "at most one record can be returned by this subquery" Error in ms access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

i'm using ms access database and i got this type of error "at most one record can be returned by this subquery" while executing the ms access query.

The Query is -

```
SELECT AccNumber, SimpleLoanBal, (select sum(MonthlyCollection) from Trans group by AccNumber) as Mo FROM Trans
```

Plz Suggest me how can i solve it

Comment: `SELECT AccNumber, SimpleLoanBal, sum(MonthlyCollection)  as Mo FROM Trans group by AccNumber, SimpleLoanBal`

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *correlated* subquery instead :

```
select t.AccNumber, t.SimpleLoanBal, 
      (select sum(t1.MonthlyCollection) from Trans t1 where t.AccNumber = t1.AccNumber) as Mo 
from Trans t;
```

However, simple `group by` should also work :

```
select AccNumber, SimpleLoanBal, sum(MonthlyCollection) as Mo 
from Trans 
group by AccNumber, SimpleLoanBal;
```

Comment: Both queries will return different results. Second makes more sense.